# Magento attribute backend type changed varchar - tekst. No layered navigation anymore

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I had to change my multiselect attribute backend type from `varchar` to `text` because I needed to select over 100 items. On `varchar` it would only save about 50 selections.

Now this works great, and I can save as many selections as needed. The problem now is when I activate the attribute for layered navigation it won't display on frontend. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

My hunch is that it should work, but the problem might be that there are no attribute values found for your attribute for any product.
The `varchar` attribute values are saved in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table and the `text` attribute values are saved in `catalog_product_entity_text` table.
You changed the attribute type, but I assume the values still remained in the `_varchar` table and Magento is looking in the `_text` table.
You should try to move the rows with `attribute_id = your attribute id` from `_varchar` to `_text` and then reindex.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I don't think this is the problem. I can display the attribute values on my product view page, but only experience a problem with layered navigation.

Comment: @Rudy. That is what actually makes me think that the problem **IS** what I suggested. In the product page `load` is called on the product model. This one looks in all the attribute value tables for any records with `attribute_id` in the allowed attributes and makes a `UNION` on all of them. In this case it is not important in which tables are the values stored. But the layered navigation looks in specific tables.  Try as a proof of concept, to save a product or 2 and reindex. then see if at least one value appears in the layered navigation.

Comment: I did save two products, reindexed, but no effect. When creating this attribute I changed varchar to text right away and before updating the attribute on any product. Can the data still be in varchar table in this case? I don't know how to check this in my database with PHPmyadmin.

Comment: I looked in my database. The data is saved in catalog_product_entity_text.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation with the multiselect attribute. They seem to be correctly populated in `catalog_product_entity_text` table but the attribute doesn't appear in layered navigation. Here is some info that may be helpful to others.

After some more debugging I found out that `text` backend_type will fail the checks in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::isIndexable()` and hence it will not be indexed for layered navigation. One workaround to make this input types indexable will be to rewrite this attribute resource model.

Or you can also override the `getBackendTypeByInput($type)` function in `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute.php` and return the `field = 'text'` when `case 'multiselect':`. I believe this will make all multiselects to be the text type.

Also, in case you are not showing multiselect attribute in layered navigation and product listing page you will not have this issue when you change varchar to text. Make sure to set `Use in Layered Navigation`, `Used in Product Listing`, `Used for Sorting in Product Listing` to `NO`

Lastly, there are more details available in Vinai's answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4883/text-attribute-in-the-layered-navigation).

Another (not recommended) solution here will be to alter table and increase the varchar field length. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html